# Running a loop for command and I want the output-name

Tags: linux, loops, patch

I'm running a loop for command and I want the output-name to be result of  concatenation of variable and a character.

I have the variable `d` (that is the name of the folder) and want to add `S` to the end of the output name for file1: `d=file1` and I want the name of the output like this: `file1S`.

When I did `-outdir "$d"s` the name of the output is just `s` and I get error msg running the second file

Tell me if more clarification is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that's what you are looking for, but if you want to add an "s" to all of your files inside the directory, you can simply run the following loop:

```
for file in *; do mv $file ${file}s; done
```